# Unable to deploy on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

I was coding normally  on visual Studio 2015 Community, I did some deployments on my  Lumia Icon device, but suddenly, when I was developing an app with OAuth 2.0 to interact with LinkedIn and tried to deploy this app, visual studio started to crash, and I got that error list

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: OAuth2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Deploying X:\...\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OAuth2\OAuth2\Bin\Debug\OAuth2_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...
2>Connecting to Device...
2>Deployment of application to device failed.
2>External component has thrown an exception.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And now this is happening with any app that I try to deploy on my phone (I've.. tried with VS2013 and got the same problem).
My device has the "Developer Mode" On and is unlocked to deploy WP apps.

**Lumia Icon**: Running Windows 10 Mobile Build 10586

Anyone already had that issue?

**UPDATE:** Error box show this

```
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device'
```

Comment: What is the error message? Check the Error List for clues.

Comment: @MikeEason The message appears like that: `Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device'`

Comment: Did you install the latest emulators for windows 10 mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The main issue was with my VS2015.

- First, I've already seen that the solution submitted by @SrdjanJovcic works fine, that one is the first step if you have a problem with your VS.
- The second step (do it if the issue remains even after installing the updates): go to Control Panel of your PC, go to Programs, and then "repair" your Visual Studio.

(My problem was with VS Studio SDK Update for W10M 10586.11, it installed the update with some erros, but after repair, everything works fine)

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't install VS 2015 Update 1, please do so:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

If it is already installed, then maybe Windows 10 SDK is out of date. See

https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-sdk

...for standalone SDK installer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i also have windows 10 mobile 10586.11 build after doing reset my device is not connected in my PC/Visual Studio 2015.

I think this is may be 10586.11 build issue please upvote this issues in Feedback app.