# Issue to deploy Windows 10 Mobile App

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am facing issue to deploy app in Windows 10 Mobile App, it showing below error while deploying.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988946667 App6
```

Refered links:
[Unable to deploy on Windows 10 Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023460/unable-to-deploy-on-windows-10-mobile) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

My Visual studio version is 14.0.25425.01 Update 3, and checking with Lumia 730 Build 10.0.14393.02004. Also i have updated PC with Windows 10 Anniversary update. i have checked all the requirement for development and checked all the check list which is found as a solution. but still facing same issue.

Someone have idea how to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is dev mode and the possibility to detect phones via USB/wifi activated on the phone?

Comment: Yes, Developer is enabled for both devices. I have connected phone Via USB.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384375/dep0001-unexpected-error-1988945906-while-deploying-windows-uwp-app-to-phone), have you tried to type in command prompt:

```
net start IpOverUsbSvc
```

Another suggestion is to remove the device from the printer and devices Menu, unplug it an ther plug in again and then try again to deploy

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Tried to co execute command, it shows message "The requested service has already been started.", also removed device and plugged again but same issue..:(

Comment: too bad, you can just try the other suggestions described in my url